# How do I convert an array to string using the jinja template engine?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have an array element called "tags" and would like to convert the array of tags to strings separated by a blank space. But how do you do that in Jinja?

I have tried:

```
{{ tags|join }}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Actually you are almost there, for join with space, just put it like this:

```
{{ tags|join(' ') }}
```

see the [jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#join) for more details

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular python in jinja tags.  an obvious choice for some simple cases is `str.join`:

```
>>> jinja2.Template(r'{{ " ".join(bar) }}').render(bar='baz')
u'b a z'.
```

You can also iterate over sequences in jinja with a `for` block:

```
>>> jinja2.Template(r'{% for quux in bar %}{{ quux }} {% endfor %}').render(bar='baz')
u'b a z '
```